# Dictionary Ordering

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, streamwriter

I am using this `var ordered = dictionary.Keys.OrderBy(x => x);` to order a dictionary.

This works great ordering the dictionary alpha-numerically and I would like to keep it this way and add a few exceptions...

So right now, the ordered dictionary looks like this for the output:

```
1: "0603C" "113456" 1
2: "0603C" "984132" 8
3: "0603R" "11115" 3
4: "0603R" "13554" 1
5: "1608C_1.0" "119764" 2
6: "1608C_1.0" "147429" 54
7: "1608R_1.0" "122951" 4
8: "1608R_1.0" "147446" 1
9: "1608R_1.0" "147448" 23
10: "3216" "110762" 2
11: "TANT23" "119764" 2
//more here...
```

..but I would like it to look like this:

```
1: "0603R" "11115" 3
2: "0603R" "13554" 1
3: "0603C" "113456" 1
4: "0603C" "984132" 8
5: "1608R_1.0" "122951" 4    //**NOTICE**: The "R" and "C" endings after 1608 and 0603
6: "1608R_1.0" "147446" 1    // were switched. I would like to switch all "C" and "R"
7: "1608R_1.0" "147448" 23   // endings if they are the same value before.
8: "1608C_1.0" "119764" 2
9: "1608C_1.0" "147429" 54
10: "3216" "110762" 2
11: "TANT23" "119764" 2
//more here...
```

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFile.FileName);
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
int j = 1;
lineList = theFuji1List.Select(line =>
{
    int nameLength = line.Name.Length;

    if (line.PartDescription != "")
        return line.PartDescription + " " line.PartNumber + " " + line.TWidth + " " + line.Name.Remove(1, nameLength - 1) + "\n";

    else
        return "N/A " + line.PartNumber + " " + line.TWidth + " " + line.Name.Remove(1, nameLength - 1) + "\n";
})
    .Where(x => !(x.Contains("FID") || x.Contains("EXCLUDE")))
    .ToLisT();

foreach (string word in lineList)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
        dictionary[word]++;
    else
        dictionary[word] = 1;
}

var ordered = dictionary.Keys.Orderby(x => x);   //This is what I think I need to change?

foreach (string key in ordered)
{
    string[] splitKey = key.Split(' ');

    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: \"{1}\" \"{2}\" {3}", j, splitKey[0], splitKey[1], dictionary[key]));
    j++;
}
```

Comment: @Cybernate: The only problem with that is that I still want the data in Ascending order *except* for the values that are similar but have a "C" or an "R".. those are the ones I would like switched

Comment: Hmmm something isn't adding up for me. You are sorting your dictionary by keys. If "0603R" is your key then you have dublicates and a dictionary will not allow that. So what is your actual key values?

Comment: @Billy: Yes if there are duplicates than the value is incremented. That is the second to last line of code that contains `,dictionary[key]));` which outputs the number of time it was found. So the actual Key value is contained in the `lineList` where it returns `line.PartDescription + " " line.PartNumber + " " + line.TWidth + " " + line.Name.Remove(1, nameLength - 1) + "\n";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify the "R" to be a "B" for the sort expression, so that it falls before "C":

```
var ordered = dictionary.Keys.Orderby(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"^(\d+)R", "$1B"));
```

This won't modify your keys - it will only affect the sort.

Comment: I like this.. but for some reason it is not working for me. I am not sure why.. it just gives me the same output as before

Comment: I think the problem is that there isn't a R in your list of keys... what does your list of keys look like? I can't tell from the code above.

Comment: @Billy: so the entire Key could be something like this: `1608C_1.0 147430 8MM C`.. The ending value **C** is what I need to look at I guess. so if the Key ends in a **R** change it to a **B**?

Comment: @theNoob - No, swapping the last letter won't work, because alphabetization rules will ignore the last letter of a string unless the strings are identical up until that point.  Ah!  I see it!  There's a typo in my Regex.  I forgot the `@` modifier for my string.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: That is quite an ugly hack. The problem just screams for a custom Comparer, not a regex hack.

Answer (score 3):

`OrderBy()` has an overload `OrderBy(Func<>, IComparer<>)` that you can pass your own comparer to.

EDIT:

You can implement your custom comparer class like this:

```
public class CustomComparer: IComparer<String>
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
         // perform comparison
         // return 0 if two items are equal, less than zero if x is less than y, and greater than zero if x is greater than y.
    }
}
```

Comment: could you go into more detail about this? I have never used IComparer

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex within an IComparer implementation and pass this into the OrderBy statement:

```
var ordered = dictionary.Keys.OrderBy(x => x, new CodeComparer());
```

Where

```
private class CodeComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string left, string right)
    {
        // TODO: Use a regex or other method to split into components
        string[] leftComponents, rightComponents;

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(leftComponents.Length, rightComponents.Length; i++)
        {
            var componentComparison = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.CompareTo(leftComponents[i], rightComponents[i]);
            if (componentComparison != 0)
            {
                if (i == 1) // Special case to flip the "R" and "C"
                {
                    return componentComparison * -1;
                }
                // TODO: Add any other special cases
                return componentComparison;
            }
        }

        // They are equal up to this point, therefore let the more detailed (i.e. bigger) item come after the shorter
        return leftComponents.Length.CompareTo(rightComponents.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get this to work.. never have been really good with pseudo-code haha