# StreamWriter ordering using Foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, streamwriter

I have some text that contains numerous values like so:

```
PartNumber    Description    Amount
Fid1          blahblahblah   999934109
0603          moreblah       12
exclude       ehh?           981
FID5          fillertext     123
fid2          fillertext     123
fid           fillertext     123
0603          fillertext     123
0603          fillertext     123
0603          fillertext     123
0402          fillertext     123
0402          fillertext     123
//etc.........etc............etc
```

I would like to print out the values that contain **"FID"**

```
int j = 1;
foreach (var line in theList)
{
    if (line.PartNumber.ToUppeR().Contains("FID"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2} {3}", 
                       j,
                       line.PartNumber,
                       line.Amount,
                       line.Description);
        j++;
    }
}
```

However, when I do this, it prints them out as follows:

```
1: Fid1 999934109 blahblahblah
2: FID5 123 fillertext
3: fid2 123 fillertext
4: fid 123 fillertext
```

and I would like to print them out numerically.. so like this:

```
1: fid 123 fillertext
2: Fid1 999934109 blahblahblah
3: fid2 123 fillertext
4: FID5 123 fillertext
```

Is there an easy, quicky way to do this?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question (or one nearly identical)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287440/dictionary-ordering -- same answer for this question I would think.

Comment: @Reddog: That was dealing with a dictionary and its' keys.

Comment: The keys were strings that you needed to break into components and apply sorting based on those components... The concept is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use the orderby clause of a LINQ query against theList:

```
int garbage;
from line in theList
where line.PartNumber.ToUpper().StartsWith("FID")
orderby (Int32.TryParse(line.PartNumber.Substring(3),garbage)) ? (Int32.Parse(line.PartNumber.Substring(3))) : 0
select line;
```

You wouldn't need the if statement in your foreach, then, either.

Comment: So how exactly would that be coded.. this does not seem to be working

Comment: The gist of it is that the return from that gives you an IEnumerable<T>, where T is whatever type you were dealing with.  So you can do:  var q = *THE QUERY SHOWN ABOVE*; foreach (var qi in q)

Comment: the `TryParse` is has an error: **No overload for method 'Try Parse` takes 1 arguments**

Comment: D'oh.  My bad on that one.  TryParse gives you a bool but expects a variable to drop its value into.  We could write a helper method or just give it a throwaway variable.  Before the query:  int crap; *snip* Int32.TryParse(line.PartNumber.Substring(3),crap) *snip*

Answer (score 1):

Fixed Jim's answer so it works: see also http://ideone.com/LIawL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestThat
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var theList = new [] {
                new { PartNumber="FID34" }
            };

            var result = theList
                .Where (line => line.PartNumber.StartsWith("FID", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                .OrderBy (line =>
                {   
                    int pnumber;
                    return Int32.TryParse(line.PartNumber.Substring(3), out pnumber)
                         ? pnumber 
                         : 0;
                });

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines could be stored in a sorted list.  The key could be the number, for non existing numbers, you could use a zero, or the key could be the entire "FID".

I am not sure if FIDs repeat, which would make this approach not doable.  Also, if the file is huge, may not be doable as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx